# How to compare distributions with errors on the data points?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, model-comparison, errors-in-variables, astronomy

Here's a mock set-up of my problem:

- I have two **non-normal** probability density distributions (PDFs), $A$ and $B$.
- Distribution $A$ has error measurements for each data point while distribution $B$ does not.
- I want to compare how well distribution *B* matches distribution $A$ **while taking into account the error measurements**.
- This test **must not** assume that the PDFs follow a specific distribution (all we know is that they are non-normal).

Essentially, I am trying to perform a goodness-of-fit measure that takes errors into account. The two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test would be an example of what I would like to do, but this does not include error measurements.

This problem has plagued me for the last month and I am surprised by the lack of solutions online, I would have thought this to have been a well encountered issue. A similar question was asked 6 years ago on this forum, but unfortunately I have been unsuccessful with the approach (most likely due to my set-up being somewhat different). Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Here's some further details about my scenario. I have a distribution of astronomical data with error measurements for each data point. The goal is to model this distribution $A$ by generating new data $B$ to best fit it. Here's an example of the procedure:

1. $B$ is generated based on parameters beyond the scope of this question.
2. $B$ is compared to $A$ in order to find how good of a fit this distribution is.
3. The goodness-of-fit measure from Step 2 is used in a sampling procedure to optimize $B$ (i.e. to improve it's fit on $A$).

Steps 2 and 3 are done $N$ times to get the best fit. My problem is that I am unsure of how to include the errors on $A$ into the goodness-of-fit measure in Step 2.

Comment: So you have two random variables $A\to M$ where you can observe the measurements $M$ but $A$ is hidden. And then you want to know whether $A$ has the same distribution as $B$. Correct? If so, this is not possible without knowing something about the dependence $A\to M$.

Comment: @frank thanks for your comment. **_A_** and it's errors are known but this is an input into a model and hence, **_A_** can change - that is why the test must be distribution-free. To add some further detail, I am using repeated sampling methods to find the distribution that best fits **_A_**. The sampling works to update **_B_** to find a distribution that better fits **_A_**.  The 'goodness' of this fit must then be defined to improve the next sampling step, and so on. I am uncertain of how to do this goodness-of-fit measure given the fact that **_A_** has errors which must be accounted for.

Comment: "The sampling works to update B to find a distribution that better fits A." So $A$ depends on $B$?

Comment: I'm not sure I would say that $A$ depends on $B$. $A$ is a target distribution for which we would like $B$ to get closer to. For each sampling iteration, $B$ is updated to better match $A$. This update depends on how well $B$ matched $A$ in the previous step (i.e. the goodness-of-fit measure). In that sense, I would say that $B$ depends on $A$ - but not the other way around as $A$ is fixed. I hope this helps and that I have not misunderstood your question.

Comment: Please state precisely what the context of your scenario is, what you want to accomplish in the end, and how you currently try to accomplish this, describing clearly every steps in the process. Example data might be helpful.

Comment: Sure: I have a distribution of astronomical data with error measurements for each data point. Goal: model this distribution $A$ by generating new data $B$ to best fit it. (1): $B$ is generated based on parameters beyond the scope of this question. (2): $B$ is compared to $A$ in order to find how good of a fit this distribution is. (3): This goodness-of-fit measure is used in a sampling procedure to optimize $B$ (i.e. to improve it's fit on $A$). Steps 2+3 are done $N$ times to get the best fit. Problem: I'm unsure how to include the errors on $A$ into the goodness-of-fit measure in step 2.

Comment: @astrobrez: Please add this new information as an edit to the post. Comments areeasily overlooled, and can be deleted. And we want posts to be self-complete!

Comment: This looks like a roundabout and suboptimal way to go about solving your problem.  Why can't you directly compare data $A$ to the distribution determined by the parameters?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @whuber I would be discounting the uncertainty on the measurement if I were to directly compare the modelled data to $A$. I believe the uncertainty should be included as the comparison directly influences how $B$ is updated. Hence, I would expect to get a different (and possibly less physical) $B$ if I left out the uncertainties on $A$.

Comment: When you compare $A$ *correctly* to a reference distribution you can handle that measurement uncertainty.  You describe a roundabout, potentially incorrect, and evidently inconvenient procedure.  I am trying to suggest that by formulating the question you actually have, rather than describing an attempted solution, you will increase the chances of getting effective answers.

Comment: @whuber I do not believe I am describing a roundabout. Nor am I outlining a solution. The problem at hand can be simplified to the title of my post - I do not know the answer to this question. In my response to your comment, I answered why one should not simply compare the distributions without including the uncertainty measurements. Your response to this is not very constructive, please elaborate further if you believe I am incorrectly comparing the distributions in question.

Comment: I am trying to be as constructive as possible by steering you away from a process that looks like it might, at best, be a real waste of time.  I can't really go any further until you disclose more about your actual problem.